# Deserialize DateTime From C# CLR

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, clrstoredprocedure

I have a json string in my CLR class like this:

```
string parameteres = "{\"Parameter\":{\"personId\":\""+PersonId.ToString()+"\",\"date\":\""+Date.Value+"\"}}";
```

The CLR class calls The REST api and passes parameters to it.
In my REST api I deserialize parameter like this:

```
JObject enterddata = JObject.Parse(jsoninput);
        string jsonparam = enterddata["Parameter"].ToString();
        var personId = new Guid();
        var date = new DateTime();
        try
        {
            JObject data = JObject.Parse(jsonparam);
            personId = new Guid(data["personId"].ToString());

            date = (DateTime)data["date"];

           //Other Codes Goes Here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

and when I reach this line:

```
date = (DateTime)data["date"];
```

The Exception occurred and doesn't convert it to DateTime. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the correct date format in this case ISO should do it

```
string parameteres = string.Format"{\"Parameter\":{\"personId\":\"{0}\",\"date\":\"{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}\"}}",PersonId,Date.Value);
```

Comment: There's no standard for dates in JSON and sometimes it's a pain. Using ISO is like a convention, but you can't be sure that every date will be in ISO format.

Comment: what is the formate for datetime ? as you see i have date time and the time part is as important as date part

Comment: @Shahram added time part.